# Onclick function does not display the table

Tags: javascript

If i did not add a function, my code will display a table but if i add an onclick function, it only displays words without the table. How do i display the word inside the table at the same time after clicking a button?

Here is my code...

```
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<table border="1">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



var myArray    = new Array();
myArray[0] = "IS001";
myArray[1] = "BUSINESS PROCESS CHANGE";
myArray[2] = "1:00PM";
myArray[3] = "4:00PM";
myArray[4] = "REIN";

function add(){
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
document.write("<td>" + myArray[i] + "</td>");
}
}
```

Comment: before working on above code , have a look on [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/meqa1wdm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because document.write() clears your document before writing to it. Also, you forgot your ending `</table>` tag. If you want to follow your approach you should probably add to innerHTML of your table instead of writing to a document (and close the table tag in html).

Comment: I have an ending </table> tag. Can you please give an example sir/maam? I can't seem to get it.

Comment: var table = document.getElementById("idOfYourTable"); then, when you have variable table which relates to your table, you can append to it's innerHTML, that is, the html that is between <table> and </table> tags in each for loop iteration, like this: table.innerHTML += ("<td>" + myArray[i] + "</td>"); += means that you're appending to it, instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Thank you very much sir/maam.

Comment: no problem. As J Santosh suggested, you should read about innerHTML and get used to it.

Comment: One last thing sir/maam. How to make it display in rows not it columns?

Comment: Table hierarchy is <table> tag, which consists of rows, marked by <tr>. Rows further consist of cells, <td>. You can make it display in rows by appending not single cells, but rows with cells inside them. Read about tables, rows and cells here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp